# Attempting to split projects out of a main solution and Nuget reference is not seeing the packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

With VS 2022 and multi-repo support I was excited to start splitting out some projects into their own solutions.  But I ran into an issue with the associated test projects.

I picked one of the smaller projects and the test project and made a new folder in my workspace for it.

I then opened the project and added the test project.

Immediately I got an error, "This project references NuGet packages(s) that are missing on this computer.  Use the NuGet Package Restore to download them ... The missing file is ..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props.".

I didn't think much of this initially and ran the package restore and the error persisted.

I should also mention that the main project doesn't have this issue; the one I opened initially.  One the project that I added to the new solution seems to have this issue.

When I run the package restore again, it says that all packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.

In playing around, I unloaded the test project and looked at the project file.  I noticed that it's referring to one folder up called "Packages":

```
 <Import Project="..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props')" />
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

I then took the opportunity to convert to nuget package reference but selecting it in the right click menu.  The above lines did not change in the project file.  Using references, it was my understanding that it was using my local "profile\ .nuget" folder.

To test that it was looking at this folder, I created the "..\Packages" folder manually and copied in the missing nuget packages.

The error went away and I was able to compile it.

However, this doesn't fix the problem.  If I were to check this solution out again, this folder would be missing.

I'm assuming that the project file is what is causing my problem.  Does anyone know how I can get a project to force looking at my profile.nuget using package reference?

Answer (score 0):

After much work I finally found a blog that talked about the differences between packages.config and packagereference.  It appears the migration didn't complete properly and didn't clean up the packages.config configuration.

I backed up the .csproj file in question

I then unloaded the project and edited the .csproj file

Anywhere that the packages were reference, I removed the entries.
Then I reloaded the .csproj file and it compiled.

When I looked at the references folder in the solution explorer I saw that the icons changed for the packages that were not found prior.

Not sure why this happened, but this is what fixed it.